# Количество работающих потоков меньше, чем ожидается C++ OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

У меня возникла следующая проблема: я пытаюсь задать 4 потока в параллельных областях, однако вижу, что работает только 2. Прим. Переменные A,B,X,previousX - {vector<vector>(MxM), vector(M) , vector(M), vector(M)} соответственно. Делал в Visual Studio.
Пример кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//ГЛОБАЛЬНЫЕ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ (входные данные)
int M = 3;
double E = 0.001;
vector<double> B{ 8,10,15 };
vector<vector<double>> A
{ 
    {3,1,1},
    {1,3,1},
    {1,2,5}
};


int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    vector<double> X(B);
    vector<double> previousX(X);
    double sum = 0;
    printf("ПРИМЕР, в котором всё в порядке и работает как надо (работает 4 потока):\n");
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum) num_threads(4) schedule(static,1) 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        Sleep(100);
        sum += 2;
        printf("Работает нить %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
    printf("sum = %lf\n", sum);
    printf("конец ПРИМЕРА\n");
    printf("===========================================\n");
    //omp_set_nested(0);
    printf("Начало работы алгоритма:\n");
    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    int iterCount = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        printf("Текущая итерация №%d\n", iterCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        {
            double sum1 = 0;
            double sum2 = 0;

            #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum1) schedule(static,1) num_threads(4) shared(A,B,X,previousX)
            for (int j = 0; j <= i - 1; ++j)
            {
                sum1 += A[i][j] / A[i][i] * X[j];
                Sleep(100);
                printf("Работает нить %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());

            }

            #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum2) schedule(static,1) num_threads(4) shared(A,B,X,previousX)
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= M - 1; ++j)
            {
                sum2 += A[i][j] / A[i][i] * X[j];
                Sleep(100);
                printf("Работает нить %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
            }
            previousX[i] = X[i];
            X[i] = B[i] / A[i][i] - sum1 - sum2;

        }

        double max = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        {
            if (max < abs(X[i] - previousX[i]))
            {
                max = abs(X[i] - previousX[i]);
            }
        }
        if (max < E)
            break;
        iterCount++;
    }
    double end_time = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Количество итераций: %d\n", iterCount);
    printf("Время выполнения: %lf\n", end_time - start_time);
    printf("Конец работы алгоритма\n");

}
```

В результате я вижу на экране, что работают нити 0 и 1.
Для примера input2_00 будет такой вывод (не до конца, конечно, но  проблему там можно увидеть, наверное)
[image: outpu2_00]

Я предварительно прогонял обычные примеры, как, например, этот

```
    double sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum) num_threads(4) schedule(static,1) 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
    {
        Sleep(100);
        sum += 2;
        printf("Работает нить %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
    printf("sum = %lf", sum);
```

И в этом просто "тесте" всё работает, как надо, и я вижу, что работают все 4 потока. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что за ошибку я допустил?

Comment: в вопрос стоит добавить полный код с примером входных данных и вывода...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я добавил, всё, что есть: код, входные и выходные данные.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Следует добавлять не "полный код", а [mcve].

Comment: @user308210, дык, матрица всего 3×3... на первый цикл приходится всего 2 итерации, а на второй — одна... или наоборот... вот и не хватает на 3 процесса всё это разнести...

Comment: @user7860670, ИМХО «самодостаточность» важнее «минимальности»... а и то и то, конечно, бывает сложно сделать... особенно неофитам...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, понял, сейчас сделаю

Comment: @Fat-Zer, Вы были правы! Я прогнал на нескольких других вариантах, где размерность как A, так и B превышает 20. И всё заработало! Они обрабатываются тем количество, которое я задаю (максимум у меня 64)

Comment: всё как у тебя написано в коде, ничего хитрого нет: 3 итерации делятся между двумя внутренними циклами по j и каждый из них уже распараллеливается независимо между 4-мя потоками... так вот 3 итерации можно разделить между циклами или как 1:2 или как 2:1 ... в любом случае разделить 1—2 «шарика» на четырёх «людей» не получится...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользователь @Fat-Zer подсказал в чём проблема! Большое спасибо! Я не принял во внимание, что количество итераций для распараллеливания крайне мало. В данном случае

> дык, матрица всего 3×3... на первый цикл приходится всего 2 итерации, а на второй — одна... или наоборот... вот и не хватает на 3 процесса всё это разнести... - Far-Zer.

То есть по существу проблемы тут нет. Всё лишь моя невнимательность и невежество.

Надеюсь этот вопрос будет кому-то полезен:)